# Supplying STDIN to program from Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a program that waits for commands on STDIN. It takes about ~2 seconds to be ready to accept those commands and after every command there needs to be at least a 1 second delay.

So far I have tried inside my script.

```
./myprogram << EOF
command1
command2
command3
EOF
```

The above works sometimes depending on how long it takes the program to start and how long it takes the commands to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the pauses are really needed? Most programs will buffer input and seamlessly run the next command when they're ready with the previous one.

If the pauses *are* needed, this is a job for `expect`. It's been a while since I've used `expect`, but you want a script that looks pretty much like this:

```
spawn myprogram                # start your program
sleep 2                        # wait 2 seconds
send "command1\r"              # send a command
sleep 1
send "command2\r"
sleep 1
send "exit\r"
wait                           # wait until the program exits
```

(A big "gotcha" is that each line of input must be terminated with `\r` (and NOT `\n`). That's easy to miss.)

This can be improved however: you waste time if a command takes less than a second to run. Or maybe sometimes a command will take longer than expected. Since most interactive programs display some sort of prompt, it's better to use that as a cue. Expect makes this very easy. For this example I'm assuming your program prints "Ready>" when it's ready to accept a new command.

```
spawn myprogram
expect "Ready>"
send "command1\r"
expect "Ready>"
send "command2\r"
expect "Ready>"
send "exit\r"
wait
```

You'll have to consult the `expect` documentation for more advance features, e.g. to add error handling (what to do if some command fails?).

Comment: Expect works very well! Thanks this was ultimately the best solution because at the end of the script I can simply add "interact" to give the user back control. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
 ( sleep 2
   echo command1
   sleep 1
   echo command2
   sleep 1
   echo command3
   sleep 1 ) | ./myprogram
```

or look into the [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) command.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sleep 1` between your commands

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

```
./myprogram << EOF
command1
$(sleep 2)
command2
$(sleep 2)
command3
EOF
```

But I would strongly suggest you to take a look at `expect`:

http://linuxaria.com/howto/2-practical-examples-of-expect-on-the-linux-cli